# ClassCastException with newer version of the class

Tags: java, serialization

I have reached that stage where a new version of class needs to be defined. With my new class definition some methods have been added, some data members type has changed. My question is, how do I continue to serve my older clients, while ensuring that my server is unchanged.

Exception

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mcruiseon.carpool.concrete.SubscribeJourneyConcrete; incompatible types for field isJourneyActive
```

With my new class, there is no `isJourneyActive`.

I know I am missing something basic here, something to do with checking the `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: serialVersionUID will not help you.  You just got to make your changes in order not to break older clients.  or are you thinking that you can dynamically load different versions of your server jar based upon the input of your client?

Comment: oh god no, different servers. I wonder, why maintain serialuid, if it wont help you ?

Comment: usually serialuid is for serialization

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is, whenever a method doesn't exist anymore, you deprecate it.

One way of going about it is having an intermediate version where the method is deprecated.

So on version 1 the method isJourneyActive is being used
On version 2 the method isJourneyActive is still being used, but you want your clients to start using the method setJourneyActive instead, so you deprecated isJourneyActive
On version 3 the method isJourneyActive is no longer there, or it is present but all it does is to throw an exception when the user tries to use it.

There are other ways, but they are more complex than just deprecating methods.